# Who really invented the integration symbol?

Tags: mathematicians, calculus, notation

Most of the sources online say that Leibniz invented the sign. There's also [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/95/126) answer on this site which says so.

That is fine. But recently when I was watching Cosmos, I noticed this:
[image]

See the integration sign on the wall? That's Newton's house. Was it a co-incidence that Leibniz used the same symbol for integration?

Comment: You mean... it's not due to Stradivarius? ![strad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LSUNf.jpg)

Comment: Integration symbol was not "discovered". It was invented. It did not exist before it was invented. Integral existed but the symbol did not:-)

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko I would say integrals were discovered because math is ahuman invention.

Comment: @Yashbhatt: I strongly disagree, and most mathematicians share my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sign of the integral was proposed by Leibniz (for indefinite integral). It is a stylized letter $S$, and $S$ stands for the "sum".

The things seen in your picture are probably metal parts of the house construction which can be seen on many old houses built of stones.
They have nothing to do with the integration symbol:-)

Remark. The modern notation for definite integral
$$\int_a^b$$ was invented by J. Fourier.

Comment: The things on the house are specifically known as [anchor plates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_plate).

Comment: Yes they are common on older UK houses. Sometimes they are other shapes, but the elongated S is one of the most common.

Comment: Ow. But that still looks cool. A nice co-incidence.

Comment: Also common in the US (in the places where stone houses exist).